# If string in list occurs in string, then add to list

Tags: c#, linq

had a look around and found many similar questions but none matching mine exactly.

```
public bool checkInvalid()
    {
        invalidMessage = filterWords.Any(s => appmessage.Contains(s));
        return invalidMessage;
    }
```

If a string is found that matches a string in the list the boolean invalidMessage is set to true.
After this though I would like to be able to add each string found to a list. is there a way I can do this using .Contains() or can someone recommend me another way to go about this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from your description, I thought here is what you want:

```
// Set of filtered words
string[] filterWords = {"AAA", "BBB", "EEE"};

// The app message
string appMessage = "AAA CCC BBB DDD";

// The list contains filtered words from the app message
List<string> result = new List<string>();

// Normally, here is what you do
// 1. With each word in the filtered words set
foreach (string word in filterWords)
{
    // Check if it exists in the app message
    if (appMessage.Contains(word))
    {
        // If it does, add to the list
        result.Add(word);
    }
}
```

But as you said, you want to use `LINQ`, so instead of doing a loop, you can do it like this:

```
// If you want to use LINQ, here is the way
result.AddRange(filterWords.Where(word => appMessage.Contains(word)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to gets the words in `filterWords` that are contained in `appmessage` you can use `Where`:

```
var words = filterWords.Where(s => appmessage.Contains(s)).ToList();
```